# how to insert xml data into sqlite database in iphone

Tags: iphone, xml, xml-parsing

I'm new in iphone development.Right now,I'm working on database.i have bunch of xml data.I want to insert xml data into my sqlite database.i made xml file.

```
<Question Index="2">
    <C_Question>2</C_Question>
    <C_Answer>2</C_Answer>
    <C_Answer_Image>2.png</C_Answer_Image>
    <C_Que_Image>2.png</C_Que_Image >

</Question>

   <Question Index="3">
    <C_Question>3</C_Question>
    <C_Answer>3</C_Answer>
    <C_Answer_Image>3.png</C_Answer_Image>
    <C_Que_Image>3.png</C_Que_Image >

</Question>
```

Answer (score 0):

follow the tutorial

NSXMLParser -

http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html

Sqlite Database -

http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/